# Dojo binding data at index 0 from array to widget

Tags: javascript, web, dojo

I have an **java script** object and i am attempting to bind the object to a widget at index 0 however i am unable to get binding to work for array objects.

I do not wish to repeat the widget for each record in the array i would simply like to bind the widget only to the salary1 in the `companyList` at index 0.

**Array:**

```
data = new Stateful({
companyList:[{id:1, salary1:300.00, salary2:200.00, salary3:400.00}]
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<span title="(a) Salary For Month One :" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase"
data-dojo-props="target:at(data,'companyList')">             

<s:textfield type="text" name="salary1" required="true"
    id="Salary1Id" placeholder="Salary Month One (e.g. 1234.00)"
    trim="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox"                                   
    data-dojo-props="value:at('rel:','salary1'),uppercase:true ,constraints:{fractional:true}, currency:'USD'"/>    

</span>
```

Comment: Instead of using an array in your model, can you iterate the array, and create your model based on the elements it contains?

Comment: this may only work in an instance where the compantList array has only one record. What about when there are multiple records in that array the html defined wont work for array data only single data items. That is why i am looking at only using the data at the 0 index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research into `dojox mvc` i was able to bind single form elements to a Stateful array object based on the index value of the record e.g 0,1,2,3... in the array.

This is a valid scenario the developer may be working with an array object which may at some point return a single record and not an array or records. If the developer wishes to bind that single record to a form field element they can use an index to access one record at a time and display to the user. They can look at the following solution.

**Data**
    data = new Stateful({
    companyList:[{id:1, salary1:300.00, salary2:200.00, salary3:400.00}]
    });

**HTML**

solution create another group accessing the array record index:

```
<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props= "target: at('rel:', 0)">


<span title="(a) Salary For Month One :" data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase"
data-dojo-props="target:at(data,'companyList')">             

<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props= "target: at('rel:', 0)">
<s:textfield type="text" name="salary1" required="true"
    id="Salary1Id" placeholder="Salary Month One (e.g. 1234.00)"
    trim="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox"                                   
    data-dojo-props="value:at('rel:','salary1'),uppercase:true ,constraints:{fractional:true}, currency:'USD'"/>    
</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks very similar to the example here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mvc/WidgetList.html#id4

I assume you are wrapping the dijit/_WidgetBase in a div setup with a WidgetList, with the _InlineTemplateMixin and setting children right?
Similar to this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
            data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
            data-dojo-props="children: at(searchRecords, 'items')">
            <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
```

Actually, your problem may also be related to the use of new Stateful instead of getStateful(), getStateful will handle the array.

So it works for me with:

```
sdata = getStateful({
companyList:[{id:1, salary1:300.00, salary2:200.00, salary3:400.00}]
});
```

And this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group"
         data-dojo-props="target: sdata">
        <h4>Declarative WidgetList using data-mvc-child-type </h4>

        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
             data-dojo-props="children: at('rel:', 'companyList')"
             data-mvc-child-type="dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox"
             data-mvc-child-props="value: at(this.target, 'salary1'),
                                                class: 'row'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Declarative WidgetList using a dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate </h4>

    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
         data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
         data-dojo-props="children: at(sdata,'companyList')">
        <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
            <div>
                <span type="text" name="salary1" required="true"
                      id="Salary1Id" placeholder="Salary Month One (e.g. 1234.00)"
                      trim="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox"
                      data-dojo-props="value:at('rel:','salary1'),uppercase:true ,constraints:{fractional:true}, currency:'USD'"/>

                </span>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
    <p>Updates to either set of CurrencyTextBoxes will be reflected in the other
</div>
```

Comment: Whats happening here is this declaration of the text field allows the field to only be present when i preform a query and binding occurs however it is not present when i run the application. How can your solution integrate with my text field declaration

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question since i am looking at accessing only index 0 and not all items in array. It works at displaying multiple items but how can i control the index value?

Comment: I would not like to use the WidgetList type however i need to use a dijit/_WidgetBase type. I am only rendering the index 0 value there is no need to repeat. This issue is causing issues when no data is sent to the field the field has not been created or is not visible for data entry. Only when data is sent then the fields gets created based on number of records in array